# What is the preferred method of updating a reference to an immutable object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, immutability

In case we have an immutable object like an ImmutableList().  What is the preferred method for using this object in a multi threaded environment?

Eg

```
public class MutableListOfObjects()
{
   private volatile ImmutableList objList;

   public class MutableListOfObjects()
   {
       objList = new ImmutableList();
   }

   void Add(object o)
   {
      // Adding a new object to a list will create a new list to ensure immutability of lists.

      // Is declaring the object as volatile enough or do we want to
      // use other threading concepts?
      objList = objList.Add(o);
   }

   // Will objList always use that lest version of the list
   bool Exist(object o)
   {
      return objList.Exist(o);
   }
}
```

Is declaring the reference volatile sufficient for achieving the desired behavior? Or is it preferable to use other threading functions?

Comment: @Romoku if something is genuinely immutable, then **that one object** is thread-safe to all common meanings.

Comment: @Romoku a *reference* is by itself thread-safe (and indeed guaranteed atomic). What *is not* thread-safe is complex organisation and changing composition of references. But that is because we aren't being immutable. If the composition was immutable, it would again be thread-safe.

Answer (score 6):

"Preferred" is contextual. The *simplest* approach is to use a `lock`, and in most cases that will do the job very effectively. If you have good reason to think that `lock` is a problem, then `Interlocked` is useful:

```
bool retry;
do {
    var snapshot = objList;
    var combined = snapshot.Add(o);
    retry = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref objList, combined, snapshot)
              != snapshot;
} while(retry);
```

This basically works on an optimistic *but checked* path: most times through, it'll only go through once. Occasionally somebody will change the value of `objList` while we aren't looking - that's fine, we just try again.

There are, however, pre-canned implementations of thread-safe lists etc, by people who really know what they are talking about. Consider using `ConcurrentBag<T>` etc. Or just a `List<T>` with a `lock`.

Comment: I tried to start a discussion about volatile and locking concepts for this example but indeed I think we can not avoid the lock.  Even in your example do 2 threads always see the correct list?  What if they start from the same snapshot, add different objects and replace the reference?

Comment: @user2377470 the point of `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is that it is exclusively atomic; say two threads A and B both run the `snapshot = ` and `combined = ` lines at the same time. When they call `CompareExchange`, it is **impossible** for them both to succeed. At least one of them is going to fail and have to retry. Note that the version of `CompareExchange` I'm using there is "as one atomic operation, compare the current value to this expected value; if it is the same, replace it with this new value; otherwise ***do nothing***; either way, tell me what the field was"

Answer (score 2):

A simple and efficient approach is to use [ImmutableInterlocked.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update). You pass it a method to perform the add. It calls your add method and then atomically assigns the new value to `objList` if the list didn't change during the add. If the list changed, `Update` calls your add method again to retry. It keeps retrying until it is able to write the change.

```cs
ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref objList, l => l.Add(o));
```

If you have a lot of write contention, such that you'd spend too much time on retries, then using a lock on some stable object (not `objList`) is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` will not help you in this case - it will not create the lock between reading `objList`, calling `Add()` and assigning `objList`. You should use a locking mechanism instead. `volatile` just protects against operation reallocations.

In your case you are creating a new list every time an object is added - usually a much better alternative would be to create the list inside a local thread variable (so that it is not subject to multi-threading issues) and once the list is created, mark it as immutable or create a immutable wrapper for it. This way you will get much better performance and memory usage.