# Is there any reason to prefer Interlocked over volatile for an Immutable Collection where updates do not depend on previous values?

Tags: c#, concurrency, immutability, volatile, interlocked

I noticed that in questions discussing immutable collections (e.g. [What is the preferred method of updating a reference to an immutable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520816/what-is-the-preferred-method-of-updating-a-reference-to-an-immutable-object))
it was advised to use `Interlocked` (or better `ImmutableInterlocked`). The reason for this seems to be for CAS, since in most cases an immutable collection is updated based off of its previous value. However, suppose I have some class wrapping an immutable collection which I expect to be accessed concurrently and where new values do not depend on old values, would using `Interlocked` still be preferred? In other words, is there any reason for me to prefer this:

```cs
public class Data {
   private ImmutableList<string> values;

   public ImmutableList<string> Read() {
       return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref values, null, null);
   }

   public void Write(IEnumerable<string> update) {
      //some arbitrary transformation that doesn't use values at all
      var newValues = update.Select(x => x + "-update").ToImmutableList(); 

      Interlocked.Exchange(ref values, newValues);
   }
}
```

over this:

```cs
public class Data {
   private volatile ImmutableList<string> values;

   public ImmutableList<string> Read() {
       return values;
   }

   public void Write(IEnumerable<string> update) {
      //some arbitrary transformation that doesn't use values at all
      var newValues = update.Select(x => x + "-update").ToImmutableList();

      values = newValues;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason. Marking the `values` field as `volatile` is enough to ensure that all threads will see the latest value stored in this field.

It should be noted though that the power of the immutable collections, and the [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1) in particular, lies on their ability to reuse most of their internal state every time they are updated. Most of them are implemented as binary trees, and updating them results in replacing a few nodes in the tree. If you are going to update the whole collection each time, then you get all the disadvantages of this approach (overhead, memory size), and none of its advantages (memory reusability).

The exception to this rule is the [`ImmutableArray<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1) struct, which is implemented internally as a simple array. It offers no reusability, but it's very performant, so it seems ideal for your case. To overcome the fact that it's a value type, you can wrap it in a [`Tuple<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-1), or store it in a field of type [`IImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablelist-1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To follow up on your second point -- would it also be valid for me to implement this internally as a volatile non-immutable collection (e.g. a regular `List`) and have `Read()` return a read only view of it (like `IReadOnlyCollection`)?

Comment: @asdf in practice you could, especially if you expect to be the only consumer of this API. But the semantics are not the same. Immutable means that nobody can change it, while readonly means that the consumer can't change it, but the owner possibly can. Here is a relevant question: [Why use ImmutableList over ReadOnlyCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165810/why-use-immutablelist-over-readonlycollection)